# Correct place to ask about wiring up my house with Ethernet cables?

Tags: discussion, site-definition

I have a question about wiring up an ethernet face plate and I'm unsure whether I should ask here, StackOverflow or Home Improvement.

Should I ask on multiple sites or just the one specfic site?

Comment: It bears saying, since nobody said explicitly: this would be totally, *totally* off-topic on StackOverflow.  That's for programming only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think both here or Home Improvement would be fine.

Whatever you do, don't cross post please — just ask your question on one site.

One [of the DIY.SE mods said](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/652/correct-place-to-ask-about-wiring-up-my-house-with-ethernet-cables):

> It would be acceptable here, but you'd likely get a better response at SuperUser

While I'm not sure we have *that* many questions on this topic, feel free to ask it here, and if you don't get a response, we'll migrate it for you.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking to just wire up the face plate, then superuser would probably be best. If you have questions about how to run the wire, that's more of a DIY thing.